# React native minheight justify content

Tags: react-native

I try to set a minHeight for a View (half height of a screen) and in this View the items need to be space-between.

Example without space between :

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={{minHeight:height}>
      <View>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>{contact.name}
          </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'grey', height: 20}}/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

When I try without the space-between , the height of the view is half screen but if i add space-between :

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={{minHeight:height,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <View>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>{contact.name}
          </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'grey', height: 20}}/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

The height of the view is increase and I don't know why. I want the height is equals to half height if the view can contains the items. And if the items in the view are too big , the height of the view will increase.

How can I solve this ?

I have made an example with expo :

[Example](https://snack.expo.io/HJwK5VejE)

Try to remove  justify content. Y ou will understand what I mean.

**EDIT**

this is my code with  the bug :

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
       <View style={{minHeight:'50%', backgroundColor:'blank',justifyContent: 'space-between'}}> 
       <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>hello </Text> 
       <View style={{backgroundColor:'grey', height: 20}}/>
       </View> 
        <Text>test</Text>
      </View>
```

The result :

[image]

The grey bar should be at the middle on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       <ScrollView>
  <View style={{minHeight:'50%', backgroundColor:'green'}}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>hello
          </Text>

  </View>
   <View style={{minHeight:'50%', backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>hello1
          </Text>

  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

You can set **minHeight:'50%'** and it will help to divide your component in half screen.

Your Solution:

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ minHeight: '50%', backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <Text style={{ height: 130, textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>hello </Text>
                    <Text style={{ height: 130, textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>hello </Text>
                    <Text style={{ height: 130, textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>hello </Text>
                    <Text style={{ height: 130, textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>hello </Text>
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'grey', height: 20 }} />
                </View>
                <Text>test</Text>
      </View>
```

Comment: yes I know but that not the problem ,  the problem is the height  increase when I add `justifyContent: 'space-between'`

Comment: <View style={{minHeight:'50%', backgroundColor:'green',justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontStyle: 'normal',fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,marginTop: 20}}>hello
          </Text>
      
  </View>

Comment: I didn't see any space

Comment: me i see a space if I add this ` <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-end',backgroundColor:'grey', height: 20}}/>`just after hello  look this example : https://snack.expo.io/HJuK7SesV

Comment: possible to share a screen shot where exactly have a space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192419/discussion-between-nirmalsinh-and-sam).